# How to handle event listner in javascript?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

[image]

I have created one web form which shown above when i click on edit button [ Highlited as a red ] then model will shown up and i put event listner on Save Changes button [ highlited as orange ]

```
What is my problem?
```

When I close this model without click on save changes button then in the background event listener is running if I again click on edit button then another save changes button event listener is running and when I click on that button then 2 event listener is executed at a same time.

```
What I need?
```

I need that solution when I close model then it will automatically stop the event listener which is running on button save changes.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't cancel event listner when you close this model, the last event listner logic will also be executed.

To Fixed: When you close the model, you need to cancel event listner.

```
element.removeEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

Comment: when I click outside of the model then it will automatically hide so how can i able to handle that

Comment: How to cancel event listener?
Should i able to handle a single/ particular event listener?

Comment: I don't know how your event listener logic is written, so I can't tell you how to cancel event listener. My idea of canceling event listener is correct.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to cancel event listeners??

Comment: It removes all eventListner why ??